# range of a function + sets problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $s$ is the set of all real $x$ such that $\dfrac{2x-1}{2x^3 +3x^2 + x} > 0$, then show that $s$ contains the intervals $(-\infty..-\frac{3}{2})$ and $(\frac {1}{2} .. 3)$.

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: @GFauxPas: Competing edits; how nice. Is $(x..y)$ a standard notation for the interval $(x,y)$ nowadays?

Comment: Out of all the variants of interval notation I've seen, this isn't most popular one, but it's the most unambiguous. It's more common in computer science than in algebra. Perhaps I should have used have used the "standard" one, though.

Answer (score 1):

You first want to find $s$. To figure out when this is greater than zero, you first have to find when it is equal to zero and undefined.

- $\frac{2x-1}{2x^3+3x^2+x} = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad 2x-1 = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad x = \frac{1}{2}$
- $\frac{2x-1}{2x^3+3x^2+x} \text{ is undefined } \quad \rightarrow  \quad 2x^3+3x^2+x = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad x(2x^2 + 3x + 1) = 0 \quad \quad \quad$
  $\rightarrow \quad x(2x+1)(x+1)=0 \quad \rightarrow \quad x = 0, -\frac{1}{2}, -1$

So, this is zero at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and undefined at $x = -1, -\frac{1}{2}$, and $0$. From here, you check which intervals between these numbers gives you something greater than zero.

[image: number line]

The possible intervals are $(-\infty -1)$, $(-1, -\frac{1}{2})$, $(-\frac{1}{2}, 0)$, $(0, \frac{1}{2})$, and $(\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$. From here, you pick a number in each interval and plug it into $\frac{2x-1}{2x^3+3x^2+x}$. If you get something positive, then that interval is part of $s$. Once you have all of $s$, you can then check to see that the intervals in your question are in $s$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you can say about the numerator and denominator individually.

$2x-1 > 0 \Longleftrightarrow x > \frac{1}{2}$

$2x^3+3x^2+x > 0 \Longleftrightarrow x(2x^2+3x+1) > 0 \Longleftrightarrow x(2x+1)(x+1) > 0 \Longleftrightarrow x > 0$ or $x \in (-1,-\frac{1}{2})$

Now how can you apply this to solve your problem?